# Polynomial multiplication CilkPlus

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp, cilk, cilk-plus

I'm trying to make a parallel cilk code of this code using cilk_for:

```
c[0:2*n-1] = 0;
    for (size_t i=0; i<n; ++i) 
        c[i:n] += a[i]*b[0:n];
```

in serial code:

```
for( size_t j=0; j<2*n-1; ++j )
        c[j] = 0; 
    for (size_t i=0; i<n; ++i) 
        for( size_t j=0; j<n; ++j )
            c[i+j] += a[i]*b[j];
```

For example:

```
x^2+x+1 
2x^2+3x+5 


C[0]=A[0]·B[0]
C[1]=A[0]·B[1]+A[1]·B[0]
.....
```

Comment: Example of Structured Parallel Programming Patterns for Efficient Computation Book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to write a cilk_for loop that loops over the output coefficients, and inside the loop, for each output coefficient, accumulate an inner product.

Call the output coefficient c[k].  The loop will look like:

```
cilk_for( k=0; k<2n-1; ++k ) 
    c[k] = __sec_reduce( a[...:...]*b[...:...:-1] );
```

The ... need to be expressions that yield the subsections that contribute to each output coefficient.  I have an intermittent Internet connection, so I'm leaving that as an exercise to the reader.

The downdload site for the book (http://parallelbook.com/downloads) has a recursive version that is asymptotically faster than the scheme above.

Comment: I test with this code: cilk_for(int k=0; k<(2*n-1); k++ ){
   c[k] = __sec_reduce_add( a[max(0,(k-(2*n-1))):min((2*n-1),k)]*b[max(0,(k-(2*n-1))):min((2*n-1),k):-1] );
  }  But not work's.

Comment: In next class teacher solve the problem, thank you for your book is awesome for students who we started.